# CSS Transcoder: Render Vendor Specific Properties

Tags: css

I was wondering if any type of "transcoder" exists, that automatically adds vender specific properties to a stylesheet? For instance if I create a stylesheet like this:

```
div.rounded {
    border-radius: 5px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

I can run the file through the transcoder, which outputs this:

```
div.rounded {
    border-radius: 5px;
    -mox-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter:Alpha(Opacity=80);
}
```

I've found a [Javascript solution](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/), but I'd rather "pre-compile" the stylesheets instead of depending on JS.

Comment: You can just link in another style sheet (a generic one).  And then depending on the order you place them in on the page will determine which one overrides the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tools that exist for this sort of thing, one very popular one is the Compass CSS Framework, online at http://compass-style.com. It is to CSS what jQuery is to JavaScript - filling in and normalizing all of the details.

With Compass (and SASS) you can do what you're asking pretty effortlessly:

```
div.rounded {
  @include border-radius; /* by default the radius is 5px */
}
```

The output will then be something along the lines of

```
div.rounded {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px / 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px / 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px / 5px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 5px / 5px;
  border-radius: 5px / 5px;
}
```

If a framework seems too heavy-handed for your needs, you could consider also a more basic [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) solution such as a [custom mixin with arguments](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixin-arguments):

```
@mixin my-border-radius($radius) {
  -webkit-border-radius: $radius;
  -moz-border-radius: $radius;
  -o-border-radius: $radius;
  -ms-border-radius: $radius;
  -khtml-border-radius: $radius;
  border-radius: $radius;
}

div.rounded { 
  @include my-border-radius(5px); 
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've looked at Compass in the past, and it's pretty neat, but it does *far* more than I want. I suppose I could use it only for the features I need, but I was hoping to find something more light-weight.

Comment: @mellowsoon Compass will permit you to use only portions of the framework at a time. For instance, to use only the border radius feature, `@import "compass/css3/border-radius"`. Of course chances are good that you'll want other features as well, such as `box-shadow`. Given that this is pre-compiled, there's no worry about resources either. Of course you could also use a bare SASS mixin if that is more appealing.